# Как вывести события по дням, начиная с сегодняшнего дня?

Tags: события, php, mysql

У меня есть база данных с такими полями:

- **id** - ид,
- **title** - название,
- **startdate** - начало события,
- **enddate** - окончание события.

Мне нужно сформировать запрос на вывод событий по датам.

Да, и самое важное. Если, например, сегодняшняя дата попадает в промежуток между датой **startdate** (начало события) и **enddate** (окончание события), это событие тоже должно выводиться.

Поиск на этом сайте и на других ничего не дал. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: вам нужно получить таблицу где на каждую дату из периода startdate-enddate расписаны события, которые есть в данном дне?

Comment: Вы правы полностью! А так же разбить их на дни, как здесь: http://www.lookatme.ru/cities/moscow/events 
А так же сделать разделы: Скоро, Сейчас и Прошедшие....

Answer (score 3):

Если надо вывести события в каком-то интервале дат, то так:

```
select
  *
from
  `tablename`
where
  `startdate` between __начало_интервала__ and __конец_интервала__
  or `enddate` between __начало_интервала__ and __конец_интервала__
order by `startdate`
```

Если события, начиная с сегодняшнего дня, то так:

```
select
  *
from
  `tablename`
where
  NOW() between `startdate` and `enddate`
order by `startdate`
```

Comment: Мне нужно вывести вот так: http://www.lookatme.ru/cities/moscow/events Этим способом мне можно будет так сделать? Или есть вариант, как мне определить что событие в данный день актуально, если дата находится в промежутке между началом и окончанием события!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
select id , title from tablename where startdate ='2012-01-12' and enddate = '2012-01-31'
```

подставляй значения начала и окончания событий в запрос и все.

Comment: Мне нужно вывести по дням все события. 
Например:
Сегодня 13 ноября 2012 года
Событие 1
Событие 2

Завтра 14 ноября 2012 года
Событие 3
Событие 4

У события есть дата начала и дата окончания. Сегодняшняя дата может быть в промежутке между датой начала и датой окончания.

Comment: ну так вытащи их все нужные, а потом распихай по массивам и выведи по группам...

`$arr['01-01-1970'][] = "$title";`

Answer (score 1):

Как и писал @Shrek подставляешь нужные даты. 
Т.е. допустим пришел запрос: выбрать между first_date и second_date, и плюс нужно выбрать событие, происходящее в этот момент, то получаем:

```
SELECT
  id,
  title
FROM
  tablename
WHERE (startdate = 'first_date' AND enddate = 'second_date')
  OR (startdate < NOW() AND enddate > NOW())
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно с группировкой по дням, то есть функция `TO_DAYS`. По ней можно сгруппировать, или даже сделать отдельное поле и хранить в нем уже результат функции, для ускорения запроса.

добавить поле и сделать UPDATE set days=TO_DAYS(startdate);
потом делаем например так

SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE days>=TO_DAYS(NOW())
ORDER BY days

этим запросом я выбираю все события от текущего дня и больше. Только за текущую дату - выводим days=TO_DAYS(NOW()) Такой вариант позволяет сделать по полю days индекс (если прямо в запросе сделать TO_DAYS(startdate) индекс не применится.
получаем массив

id title startdate days

1 новость 2012-11-20 10:50:33 735192

2 новость2 2012-11-20 12:10:22 735192

3 новость3 2012-11-21 17:10:22 735193

Соответственно при каждой смене значения в поле days выводим новый заголовок и т.п.

Comment: А можно пример реализации этого?

Comment: добавить поле и сделать UPDATE set days=TO_DAYS(startdate);
потом делаем например так 
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE days>TO_DAYS(NOW())
ORDER BY days
получаем массив 
id title startdate days
1 новость 2012-11-20 10:50:33 735192 
2 новость2 2012-11-20 12:10:22 735192
3 новость3 2012-11-21 17:10:22 735193

Соответственно при каждой смене значения в поле days выводим новый заголовок и т.п.